# Centering navbar links does not want to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I cannot seem to get the links in my  bar to be in the centre, it either goes to the right or to the left. the Logo on the left is fine and the login & sign-up buttons are fine too, it's just the middle links that seem to be giving me issues.

Navbar:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg border-bottom navbar-white bg-white padding-bottom" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>

    <!-- logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?= urlFull(); ?>">
            <img src="<?= urlFull(); ?>images/img-logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="GM SEO Services">
        </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

      <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['member'])) { ?>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="<?= urlFull(); ?>" class="nav-link <?= ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /index.php ") ? "active " : " "; ?>" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="services.php" class="nav-link <?= ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /services.php ") ? "active " : " "; ?>">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="software.php" class="nav-link <?= ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /software.php ") ? "active " : " "; ?>">Software</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.php" class="nav-link <?= ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /contact.php ") ? "active " : " "; ?>">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <?php } else { ?>

      <?php $globId = getGlobalId($member); ?>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="my-account.php" class="nav-link <?= ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /my-account.php ") ? "active " : " "; ?>" aria-current="page">My Account</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="licenses.php" class="nav-link <?= ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /licenses.php ") ? "active " : " "; ?>" aria-current="page">Licenses</a></li>
      </ul>
      <?php } ?>

      <div class="col-md-3 text-end">
        <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['member'])) { ?>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2 <?= ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /login.php ") ? "active " : " "; ?>" href="login.php" role="button">Login</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="sign-up.php" role="button">Sign-up</a>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

What I have tried is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills me-auto">
```

This moves the links far left towards the logo.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills text-center">
```

This brings the Login & Signup buttons over towards the links.

I have tried a few variations and everything I try moves the links to either the left or to the right, am I missing something at all? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please reduce your HTML sample to not include PHP. It's not relevant here.

Comment: Also, tag your Bootstrap _version_.

Comment: Since this is a question about CSS and HTML, including PHP code is not very helpful. Instead include the HTML, ideally in a code snippet. See [mre] for more information.